# Sendmail() localhost em LOTE

Tags: php, mysql, email

Amigos, estou conseguindo enviar email normalmente utilizando sendmail() localhost, da seguinte forma:

sendmail.ini

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
smtp_ssl=auto
auth_username=meugmail
auth_password=minhasenha

smtp_ssl=tls
tls_certcheck off
```

php.ini

```
[mail function]

SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
sendmail_from = meugmail
sendmail_path = "C:\"\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header = Off
```

Na hora de enviar eu faço uma busca em uma tabela específica do meu banco, onde as mensagens estão gravadas, e vou enviando uma a uma mais ou menos assim:

```
$sqlemail = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id_email, id_msg, id_remetente, id_destinatario, tipo_destinatario, email, assunto, 
                              texto, arquivo_anexo, data FROM tbl_msg_email_temp LIMIT 1");
$sqlemail->execute();
$sqlemail->store_result();

if($sqlemail->num_rows > 0){//Achei emails há serem enviados

    $sqlemail->bind_result($id_email, $id_msg, $id_remetente, $destinatario, $tipo, $email_user, $assunto, $texto, $arquivo_anexo, $data);
    $texto =  nl2br($texto);
    $sqlemail->fetch();
    $sqlemail->close();
```

Então uma vez localizada uma ou mais msgs a serem enviadas, eu vou enviando uma a uma com a função mail()

```
if (mail($to, $assuntoHTML, $mensagem, $headers)) {
```

Como eu disse, isso funciona perfeitamente, mas agora eu me deparei com a possibilidade de enviar a mesma msg para várias pessoas, e da forma que está, eu devo me conectar ao google toda vez deixando o processo muito lento, eu gostaria mesmo de me conectar uma única vez e enviar as 1.000, 10.000 msgs.

isso é possível ?

obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a resposta encontrada no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389035/php-mail-multiple-recipients), você poderia enviar a mesma mensagem para vários destinatários da seguinte forma:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $addresses[] = $row['address'];
}

$to = implode(", ", $addresses);

$headers .= "BCC: {$to} \r\n";

mail(null, $assuntoHTML, $mensagem, $headers);
```

Comment: O.o isso ai vai criar um corrente de email.

Comment: Ah, tem um jeito de enviar um CCO. Mas esqueci :\

Comment: Vai no no `$headers`, se não me engano é `$headers .= "Bcc: $to \r\n";`

Comment: Corrigido, amigo, @rray

Comment: Entendi, no caso da mesma msg, caso se tratar de msgs personalizadas, vc saberia me dizer como enviar para muitos se conectando uma única vez ao GMAIL ?

Comment: Amigo, você pode simplesmente utilizar classes prontas para esse fim. Dê uma olhada no [Swift Mailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478906/using-phps-swiftmailer-with-gmail), é muito fácil enviar um e-mail via g-mail (com uma conexão só) e é mais fácil de estruturar o código!